# Difference between a hole and a pit?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

This thing has long since confused me.

When do use a pit and a hole ?

What do we call if they happen to be on a road or on a street ?

Please tell me if there are any more synonyms that i should know.

Answer (score 4):

A hole (usually) passes entirely through a surface, or an object.  A pit is (usually) a concavity.

A "pothole" is a place on the paved surface of a road where the paving has been worn away, revealing the underlying layer.  The top layer has been worn away.

But there are times when concavities are called holes, and times when tears or (earth) penetrations are called pits.

Comment: So if i say the following sentence, would you say that it's correct ? -  'The roads in my area are so pathetic that you can't tell whether there are potholes along the road or a road along the potholes.'

Comment: Pretty close to perfect. The only real issue is the way you use the word "along". The idiomatic way to say this is "... so pathetic that you can't tell the potholes from the road."